# How to Load Images in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to load images in my React.js application and I can't get them to load. I've looked at a bunch of SO questions and none of them solved it. In my webpack.config.js file under module and rules I have the url loader.

```
{
    test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
    use: {
      loader: 'url-loader',
    },
}
```

Then in my App.js file I have this.

```
import React from "react";
import '../css/App.css'
import locationImg from '../public/location.png'

function App() {
console.log(locationImg)
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Contact Me</h1>
        <img src={locationImg} />
      </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

My file structure looks like this

```
-src
    -Components
      -App.js
    -css
    -public
      -location.png
```

When I load this on the webpack live server, the image doesn't load. Why won't the image load?

Comment: You should not have to import or edit your settings when using your images. You should be able to use its relative path. Did you try `/public/location.png` in your img tag's src? If that does not work, try simply `location.png` with and without the forward slash.

Comment: Also you wrote in your question that your public folder is inside your src folder. It should be a sibling, not a subdirectory.

Comment: i tried `<img src='/public/location.png' />` and all the other ones you specified and in all of them I got errors similar to this. GET http://localhost:8080/public/location.png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Taking the public folder out of the src did the trick. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
const location= require(../public/location.png');

<img src={location} />
```

Comment: I've tried that and it gives me this error Error: Can't resolve './public/location.png' in src/Components

Comment: I've tried that one too. I get this error in the console. GET http://localhost:8080/[object%20Module] 404 (Not Found)

Comment: this error for the path of image try   '../public/location.png' or './public/location.png'

Comment: both of those give me the same two errors previously specified

Comment: what about <img src='./public/location.png' />

Answer (score 0):

Try change the code to

```
<img src={locationImg.default} />
```

or

```
import * as locationImg from '../public/location.png'
```